# Stop affecting existing html

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am working on a widget/gadget based website, where the user can have the same the same widget/gadget on the same page at the same time.  For example, the following could be a widget/gadget:

```
<div class="widget widget_1">
    <div class="header widget_header_1">
        <input type="text" class="textbox_1"/><input type="button" class="button_1"/>
    </div>
    <div class="content widget_content_1"></div>
    <div class="footer widget_footer_1"></div>
</div>
```

I can then have many of these on screen at once, which is why I am using classes instead of id's.

on document.ready, I run a function which generates default values for `widget_content_1`.  The problem is that when another of these identical widget is added by the user, the default function resets all `widget_content_1` widgets to the default value.  How do I stop this from happening and how do I only apply default values to the newly added widget without affecting the others?

The code currently looks like this:

```
// on document ready:
function_default();

...

function function_default() {
    $('.widget_content_1').empty().append("default content here");
}
```

Anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a position specific selector is a solution, but also error prone if the newest widget is not always in a specific position.

I would simply add a flag, `new` to the newly created widget, in whatever place it is created:

```
<div class="widget widget_1 new">
    ...
</div>
```

And then use this selector in jQuery:

```
function function_default() {
    $('.widget.new').empty().append("default content here").removeClass('new');
}
```

If n number of new widgets have been created, this will also add the default content to all of them.

Comment: This is almost perfect.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery `:last` selector to select the last (and hopefully the newly added) widget like this:

```
function function_default() {
    $('.widget_content_1:last').empty().append("default content here");
}
```

If there is a single widget, then this will select the first one.

Answer (score 0):

If the newly created one is appended, could you use the `:last` selector or `.last( )` function?

E.g.:

```
$('.widget_content_1').last( ).empty( ).append('Default content')
```